# Show that $S_n = X_1 + X_2 +\dots + X_n$ satisfies the Law of Large Numbers

Tags: statistics, characteristic-functions, law-of-large-numbers

Be $X_1, X_2, X_3, X_4, \dots $ a sequence of uniformly limited independent random variables. Show that $S_n = X_1 + X_2 + \dots + X_n$ satisfies the Law of Large Numbers. My work, so far:

If $X_j$ goes to $U[a_j,b_j]$, so $\Omega_{X_j}(t)=\frac{e^{itb_j}-e^{ita_j}}{it}$, where $\Omega_A (t)$ is the characteristic function of an A random variable.

$$\Omega_{S_n}(t)=\frac{e^{it \sum^n b_j}-e^{it \sum^n a_j}}{it^n},\qquad
\Omega_{S_n/n}(t)=\Omega_{S_n}(t/n)=\frac{e^{it \bar{b}}-e^{it \bar{a}}}{(\frac{it}{n})^n}$$

Comment: By "uniformly limited", do you mean uniformly bounded?  But that doesn't say $X_j$ has a uniform distribution.

Comment: So, what would you do then?

Comment: I suspect that saying "$S_n$ satisfies the Law of Large Numbers" is saying $\frac1N \sum\limits_{n=1}^N S_n \to k$ as $N \to \infty$ for some finite constant $k$ which depends on the $X_i$.  You seem to have read it as $\frac1n S_n \to k$

Comment: @Henry That may not be true if the means are not the same.  But look up "Kolmogorov's strong law".